# How to represent a term document matrix like heatmap and word cloud in R?

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, word-cloud

I have a term document matrix, shown below. How can i represent it like heatmap and word cloud?

[image]

Comment: Look at the package `wordcloud`. Mixed with package `tm` it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Word Cloud:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
data(crude)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords()))
wordcloud(crude)
```

For Heatmap:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
df <- melt(as.matrix(tdm))
df <- df[df$Terms %in% findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 10), ]
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(Docs), Terms, fill=log(value))) + geom_tile() + xlab("Docs") + scale_fill_continuous(low="#FEE6CE", high="#E6550D")
```

Comment: Great answer. How can I have dendrogram on both rows and columns?